# Accessing two array indexes at once (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

I am creating a little home automation system for myself using an arduino uno, wifi shield, and relay shield. I am still in the early stages, but right now I basically need to know if the following is possible/would work:

```
char anArray[2];
...

void loop()
{
   anArray[1,2] = client.read();
}
```

In this scenario, I know for a fact that each client transmission will be exactly two characters long. The code above(along with a lot of other code I wrote, does compile, but I need to know if the method above would actually assign the characters of the client request to the array.
Finally, I would really appreciate some knowlege of how to connect to the server I am creating with the Arduino using a computer or phone, allowing for remote control. Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, did you try it out? It might compile, but `anArray[1,2]` simply discards the `1,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you need to assign to a temporary variable, and then use the temporary variable to assign the array elements:

```
char temp = client.read();
anArray[0] = temp;
anArray[1] = temp;
```

Also note that I changed the indexes, remember that array indexes are zero-based.

Comment: Thank you, knowledgeable Joachim. Yes, using 1,2 instead of 0,1 was careless. And consider this: the return from client.read() is a byte in size(but only containing 2 chars). I want to copy each char into a separate array element. How can I do this?